# Mock-service and Grails jaxrs integration test

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, jax-rs, integration-testing

I want to test a grails application(using jaxrs) and it's integrations.  For this task I hope to use the awesome IntegrationTestCase-class from the jaxrs plugin.
This is challenging because I want to mock/replace a service within my application. With “pure” Spring I would create testcontext and manually wire up the mock. I have no idea how to do this in grails. 
I’ve tried to access the ApplicationContext directly

```
Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.registerMockBean("myService", new MyMock())
```

This does not seem to work as the mock is not used during the test. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to define in test class his way:

```
    @Before
    void before() {
        Holders.grailsApplication = grailsApplication

        defineBeans {
            myService(MyMock)
        }
    }
```

It's for jUnit tests. If you use Spock, rename **before()** to **setup()** and see [Spock basics](https://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/SpockBasics) Fixture Methods.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think a can combine IntegrationTestCase with the  defineBeans-closure.

Comment: Then do you really need integration test?